# Datepicker for Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, web-frontend

What I could use for date instead of 'datepicker' because it don't work correct and I heard it's not compatible from bootstrap 3+.

If I paste example datepicker code to clear html page it works correct but if I paste it to my page inputs do themself smaller(height). I checked where the problem is and probably problem is by bootstrap-combined.min.css If I delete it everything back to standard size(without datepicker input) but datepicker doesn't works. I tried to update version(in examples is 2.2.2) of bootstrap-combined-min.css but probably it's not exist.

If exist any alternative way, write about it.

Please for answer like for beginner because I don't understand enough scripts and adding it to page.

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML markup (datetimepicker code)?

Comment: @BruceWayne how I can paste here this code?
If I try paste it here I see "too long by *** characters".

P.S Sorry I'm new on SO.

Comment: @Damianm you don't have to paste your entire code, just the datetimepicker part only.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
  <input type="text"></input>
  <span class="add-on">
    <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
  </span>
</div>



  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
    language: 'pt-BR'
  });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.